# Is there a Google Play Movie API?

Tags: google-play

Trying to integrate Google Play's Movies and Series into http://www.BAGmovies.com, so our users can know which movies are for rent in Google Play

Is there a Google Play API for movies? I'm looking to

- Make a call (e.g. with a Movie Title or Movie ID)
- Get Availability / Price

Thanks!
Jaime

Answer (score 2):

No, Google doesn't provide APIs for the features used in Google Play, Google Movie or Google Music apps. There are some inoffical Documentations/Libraries (reverse engineered), but I wouldn't recommend the usage of them. Especially not in a commercial background.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, There is an API you can enable for Google [Movies Anywhere](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/google/moviesanywhere.googleapis.com?pli=1). However, the API is for app integration, I'm not sure if you are trying to do web.

It's possible you do not need to use the API - an example intent for your first point:

```
Intent movie = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/movies/details?id=" + movieId));
startActivity(movie);
```

Comment: where is the movie ID obtained from?